# Add class later request was completed with Angular loading bar

Tags: angularjs, loading

I'm working my frontend with angular and [angular-loading-bar](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar), in the controller I put this code.

```
$rootScope.$on("cfpLoadingBar:completed",function(){
   $(".animated").addClass("fadeIn");
});
```

or

```
$scope.$on("cfpLoadingBar:completed",function(){
   $(".animated").addClass("fadeIn");
});
```

When the all XHR requests have returned, I want to add a clase in my section content, but the code inside event don't run.

How is the correct way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check that you use appropriate event name. For example, are you sure thet its name is `cfpLoadingBar:completed`? Maybe its a `cfpLoadingBar::completed` (its a very common pattern) or something else?

Second, ensure that you have to subscribe to this event using `$rootScope`. Maybe you have to subscribe for it in some concrete controller witj its own `$scope`?

And as a big suggestion: **DO NOT USE JQUERY AND ANGULAR TOGETHER IN YOU CODE, DO NOT MESS IT UP!!!** Angular has a built in possibility to work also as a jquery. All that you need is to call `angular.element()` which returns you an element as if would use jquery. In your case you can write `angular.element(".animated").addClass("fadeIn");` and it will do the same thing, but in angular way

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I use both cfpLoadingBar::completed and cfpLoadingBar:completed but don't run this event.

In the other hand I only have one controller by one section, it ran but I needed add a main controller and registered this event and propagate up the event  with $broadcast in my child controller.

This is code in MainController

```
$scope.$on('cfpLoadingBar:completed', function(event, data) {
      angular.element(".animated").addClass("fadeIn");
  });
```

And This is code in other Child Controller

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('cfpLoadingBar:completed');
```

it is the only way to achieve, I don't know why XD

Thanks Andrew this way is better angular.element()